# Fixed left and right arrow buttons at the either side of the horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scrollview in my app. On either side of the scrollview, I wish to keep a left and a right arrow buttons (ibLeft & ibRight below), which should be visible all the time and should not hide behind the horizontal scrollview images at any point of time.

The issues faced by me are:

1. Somehow, the horizontal scrollview kind of overlaps the two buttons.
2. Also, I do not see any thing happening when I set onclick listeners for the buttons. I read somewhere that this is a problem when we have a horizontal scrollview.

Kindly help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelBt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="NEWS" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="LIVE T.V." />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="YOUTH" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtmp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Video will come up here" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RelBt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtmp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hsv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView..../>
<ImageView..../>
<ImageView..../>
<ImageView..../>
<ImageView..../>

                            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The java file is

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    HorizontalScrollView hSV;
    ImageButton ibLeft,ibRight;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ibLeft=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibLeft);
        ibLeft.setOnClickListener(this);

        ibRight=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibRight);
        ibRight.setOnClickListener(this);

        hSV=(HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.ibLeft){
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(v.getId()==R.id.ibLeft){
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position your `HorizontalScrollView` relative to your `ImageButtons`:

```
//...
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RelBt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtmp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hsv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ibLeft"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ibRight"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
//...
```

Regardind the buttons not receiving click events they are probably covered by the `HorizontalScrollView`, also you've set the same id(of the left button) to both buttons, left and right in the `onClick()` method.

Comment: fadingEdgeLength doesn't work, doesn't cover the arrows.

Comment: @JPM Calculate the proper value based on your images dimensions.